# Rails 6 Ajax spinner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, spinner

I'm trying to get an Ajax spinner working in Rails 6. My previous solutions no longer work.

in applications.js

```js
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    document.ready(function() {

      // hide spinner
      (".spinner").hide();

      // show spinner on AJAX start
      (document).ajaxStart(function(){
        (".spinner").show();
      });

      // hide spinner on AJAX stop
      (document).ajaxStop(function(){
        (".spinner").hide();
      });

    });
})
```

It doesn't like "document.ready".

Comment: ready, hide, ajaxStart, and ajaxStop are jquery functions. Have you included jquery?

Comment: You're right - I thought I had it loaded but I checked in the console - and it wasn't. Now it's loaded. I don't get any errors now but the above won't show or hide the spinner. My div is:
<div id="spinner" class="spinner_css" style='display:none'><img src="/assets/spinner.gif" alt="Spinner" /></div>
If I take off the " style='display:none' " so  (".spinner").hide(); can hide the div  on document ready ... I just see the spinner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: jQuery functions require $ or jquery, For example $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(".spinner").hide();
});

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors need to use the jQuery $ function

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
      // hide spinner
      $(".spinner").hide();

      // show spinner on AJAX start
      $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $(".spinner").show();
      });

      // hide spinner on AJAX stop
      $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        $(".spinner").hide();
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, still not firing. No errors in the browser. Also tried:
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {

Comment: added the  

$(".spinner").delay(3000).hide(); 

to delay incase it's happening too fast - tried script tags in the body. Have it in 

app/javascript/controller/spinner_controller.js 

with 

import "controllers" in app/javascript/packs/application.js

(I'm struggling with the new structure but have a search javascript working in the same location which also uses jQuery)

Comment: I'm using flatpickr - which works - in application.js I have:  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
 flatpickr("[data-behavior='flatpickr']",{
  altInput: true,
  altFormat: "F j, Y",
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
 })
})

Comment: but doesn't work on an ajax call. I had to add: flatpickr("[data-behavior='flatpickr']",{
 altInput: true,
 altFormat: "F j, Y",
 dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
}).   to the js file called from the controller's action - then it works.